# I am trying to code for a tic- tac - toe game

Tags: c

I am trying to create a function to enter x and o in my board which has counters to 1 - 9 already. Can someone explain me the algorithm and logic so i can try and code accordingly
If someone can guide me through, i am going through different examples but nothing specifically for shorter functions

```
//function to initialize board and my main and last is the function with printf commands


     #include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3
void InitializeBoard(int m, int n , char board[][n]){
    int c =1;
    for(int i =0; i<m; i++){
        for(int j=0; j< n; j++){
            board[i][j] = c+'0';
            c++;

        }

    }
    return;
}

void PrintBoard(int m, int n, char board[][n]){


    printf("\n %c | %c  | %c  \n", board[0][0],
           board[0][1], board[0][2]);
    printf("\n--------------\n");
    printf("\n  %c | %c  | %c  \n", board[1][0],
           board[1][1], board[1][2]);
    printf("\n--------------\n");
    printf("\n %c | %c  | %c  \n\n", board[2][0],
           board[2][1], board[2][2]);
    return;
    }
int main() {
    printf("Let's begin the game ! \n " );

    char choice;
    int m , n ;
    char board [MAX][MAX] ;



    do {
        printf("Press 'p' to print the tic-tac-toe board.\n");
        printf("Press 'c' to create the tic-tac-toe board with some X and O celss.\n");
        printf("Press 't' to test is the tic-tac-toe board is valid or invalid.\n");
        printf("Press 'w' to predict winning cell for the player X and O.\n\n");
        printf("Press 'e' to exit\n");

        scanf(" %c", &choice);

        switch(choice){
            case 'p' :

                InitializeBoard(m,n,board);
                PrintBoard(m,n, board);
                break;
            case 'c' :


            default:
                choice =-1;
        }
    }while(choice!=-1);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect output

```
        1|2|3
        -----
        4|5|6
        -----
        7|8|9
```

Comment: Just google for the same. tic-tac-toe code in any language is very easy to find over the net. Here see this on [geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-of-tic-tac-toe-game/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is uninitialized variables which you are using to fill the board.

```
int m , n ;
......

InitializeBoard(m,n,board);
PrintBoard(m,n, board);
```

You need to initialize them to number of rows and columns.

```
int m = MAX  , n = MAX;
```

Comment: that worked thank you, but is there another function that i can use apart from printf?